# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot coerce value to an empty range: maximum 8.989999 is less than minimum 8.99

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to achieve a rounding effect on values from rangeSlider (Compose):

```kotlin
var sliderPosition by remember {mutableStateOf(minSelected..maxSelected)} // passed in the function parameters from the view model when the composable is created
RangeSlider(
            values = sliderPosition,
            onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it },
            valueRange = minPrice..maxPrice, // passed in the function from the view model when the composable is created
            onValueChangeFinished = {
                onPriceFilterRangeChanged( // just saves the value in the viewModel
                    sliderPosition.start.toTwoDecimalPlaces(),
                    sliderPosition.endInclusive.toTwoDecimalPlaces()
                )

            }
)
```

However in rare cases when the range is small (sometimes even one value so: 8.99 - 8.99)
when both of the sliders are in the same place and the user moves them they sometimes crash the app with the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xx.xxx.debug, PID: 13355
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot coerce value to an empty range: maximum 8.989999 is less than minimum 8.99.
        at kotlin.ranges.RangesKt___RangesKt.coerceIn(_Ranges.kt:1645)
        at androidx.compose.material.SliderKt$RangeSlider$2.invoke(Slider.kt:398)
        at androidx.compose.material.SliderKt$RangeSlider$2.invoke(Slider.kt:306)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl$invoke$1.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:127)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl$invoke$1.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:127)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:145)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2351)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2618)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3205)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3183)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:252)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3183)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3148)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:746)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:876)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:485)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:454)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1299)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1309)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:923)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:847)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1283)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@42f27db, androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@49ae278, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@7c32d51, AndroidUiDispatcher@38f29b6]
```

The rounding function looks like this:

```
fun Float.roundToTwoDecimal(): Float {
    return round(this * 100) / 100.0f
}
```

I've searched for this particular problem for a bit and found stuff similar to: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230236391, but they did not even give me a hint how to fix it

Comment: I don't know anything about Compose specifically, but calling your rounding function with *8.989999* returns *8.99*. So is it possible your slider is returning the raw *8.989999* value, and that's being combined with the **stored, rounded** value to create an invalid range? If you're getting values like *8.989999* you should probably store them as-is, so you can compare like with like, and the rounded versions should be considered "different data" e.g. a display version. That, or always round all values before you use them - just make sure you're being consistent

Comment: any solution for this I'm also facing same